# Has Flutter changed how it handles an Image as AppBar title?

Tags: flutter, flutter-appbar, flutter-image

In my Flutter app I am using a png image as the title inside the `AppBar`. It seems in the last 24h to have changed how it handles the resizing of the image.

Over the last month or two this has been working fine: inside my `MaterialApp` my `StatefulWidget` returns an `AppBar` inside a `Scaffold`, which has its `title` set to `Image.asset(assetName)`. The `Image` was automatically being scaled down properly to fit neatly within the `AppBar` on-screen, once I had added a bit of `padding`.

Yesterday, this broke. I've checked the diffs and nothing has changed that would obviously affect this part of the code since when it was working. I now have the image being shown at full size, which is about 3 times too big for the space available and so it's being cropped.

I've tried adding `fit: BoxFit.contain`, and indeed every other possible `BoxFit` option - absolutely no difference.

I have ended up using `height: AppBar().preferredSize.height * 0.6` on the `Image` as a workaround.

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                     vertical: 10,
                   ),
            child: Image.asset(kLogoImage, height: 
                     AppBar().preferredSize.height * 0.6),
                   ),
...
```

But I don't understand why this has suddenly changed, without my seeming to have done anything that affects it. Has there been a shift in Flutter itself somehow that's broken this??

Comment: Check if this change 8 days ago could have made that happen: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/42936

Comment: That's exactly it. Thanks. (Thought I was going crazy...)

Comment: Now does the image always display at its full height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a change in Flutter, as per Pablo's comment above.

Answer (score 2):

To restore the original AppBar layout behavior, wrap the AppBar's title in a SizedBox with height: kToolbarHeight.

```dart
appBar: AppBar(
  title: SizedBox(
    height: kToolbarHeight,
    child: Image.asset(kLogoImage),
  ),
),
```

The previous example introduced 10 pixels of vertical padding, so:

```dart
appBar: AppBar(
  title: SizedBox(
    height: kToolbarHeight,
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      child: Image.asset(kLogoImage),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Also discussed here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/44550#issuecomment-552586000.